# AVAssetTrack understanding preferredTransform property

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, video, avfoundation

I faced with misunderstanding of preferredTransform property of [AVAssetTrack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassettrack). In my app I am extracting video frames and trying to display them but I don't understand how the frame data is laid out and what means [preferredTransform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassettrack/1389837-preferredtransform) property (if this transform which I must apply to the frame data then image must be displayed correctly but it is not visible at all; if this transform is already applied to the image then overused must return the image back to the normal state but it is also don't work).

In some tutorials I saw this code to fix transform

```
extension AVAssetTrack {
    var orientation: (orientation: UIImage.Orientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
        let transform = self.preferredTransform

        var assetOrientation = UIImage.Orientation.up
        var isPortrait = false
        if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .right
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .left
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .up
        } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .down
        }
        return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
    }

    var fixedVideoTransform: CGAffineTransform {


        let videoOrientation = self.orientation

        var resultTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        // Now we need fully discard all video transforms and show video as it was in preview
        switch videoOrientation.orientation {
        case .down:
            let rotationFix = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width - videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.tx, y: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height - videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.ty)
            resultTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(rotationFix)

        case .right:
            let rotationFix = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height - videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.tx, y: -videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.ty)
            resultTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(rotationFix)

        case .left:
            let rotationFix = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x:  -videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.tx, y: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width - videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.ty)
            resultTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(rotationFix)


        default:
            resultTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform // default landscape orientation nothing need to do there
        }

        return resultTransform
    }
}
```

This looks OK but what if video rotation is not equal to 90 180, -90 or -180 degrees.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Did you find the answer? Can you add that tutorial link that outlines how to fix the transform?

Comment: Sorry @IanBytchek but I had to end up with discarding all transforms before working with video.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, see my post here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64161544/1821701